# Why can not use hex Int in kotlin method intArrayOf?

Tags: java, kotlin, int

I found a strange problem in Kotlin.

I can assign a hexadecimal integer to an Int variable, just like:

```
private val a = 0xFFFF0000    //works good
```

but I can't use this hex integer in `intArrayOf`:

```
private val array: IntArray = intArrayOf(0xFFFF0000)
```

IDE prompts: *the integer literal does not conform to the expected type Int*.
[image]

Does anyone know why? and is there anyway to use `0xFFFF0000` in `intArrayof`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because 0xFFFF0000 is `Long` Type,

You can use `private val array: IntArray = intArrayOf(0xFFFF0000.toInt())`

to change type from Long to Int

or declare `LongArray` type

like `private val array: LongArray = longArrayOf(0xFFFF0000)`

Comment: I found that  `private val a: Int = 0xFFFF0000` is not work. It'right that 0xFFFF0000 is `Long` Type, and I got the reason. But, why `0xFFFF0000` is a `Long` type, I think it's `Int` type.

Comment: If the first hex digit is 8 or higher, the positive number is too big to fit in an Int. Kotlin treats this differently than Java, which lets the number wrap around to negative. This is considered a bug by the JetBrains team, but it's one they haven't fixed in six years: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4749?_ga=2.112688001.407694624.1573479899-370803150.1565276011

Answer (score 2):

While `0x7FFF_FFFF` is of typ Int, hex literals starting from `0x8000_0000` are of type Long.

You need 32 bit to store `0x8000_0000`. While Int is signed, the value is (the least one, that is) too big to be stored in an Int.

You can use negative hex literals though

```
val a: IntArray = intArrayOf(-0x1_0000)
```

If you are on the JVM, you can check with

```
a.forEach { println(Integer.toHexString(it)) }
assert(0x7FFF_FFFF == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
assert(-0x8000_0000 == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
```